# mysql table with many records and new index still slow

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following table with a little less than 600,000 records:

```
CREATE TABLE `organization` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `org_company_name_7467253` (`company_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=589816 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The table was running slow so I created an index on company_name:

```
CREATE INDEX `org_company_name_7467253` ON `organization` (`company_name`);
```

I am doing several queries like the following that are taking around 30 seconds each:

```
for e in Entity.objects.all(): #around 2000 records - select * from entities
    if Organization.objects.filter(company_name__icontains=e.name): #600,000 records - select * from organizations where company_name = entity.name
          print 'contains organization'
```

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: 600k is nothing. That query should be really fast. Probably something else is wrong. Can you show us the explain plan?  [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I added the actual loop I am doing.

Comment: I dont know what is that?  What lenguaje is that? (maybe add aditional tag) Or explain what is soppose to do? Otherwise we will have to guess. But looks like you are doing the same query 2000 times? that of course will take time. Try to be specific on what/where is the problem, because you start the question with a query with only a `where`  condition, and now there is a loop. And again the explain plan will help a lot.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza they are selects in django python.  I added the select next to the code

Comment: 30 seconds each query or the whole loop? My answer assume the second one. Because if is the first case again we need the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same query 2000 time take time. So 30000 ms isnt much is just 15 ms for query.

So you either do multithread to send multiple request at the same time to db, like I did here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/155263/95510

Or do a JOIN in the db to get the same result in a single query.

Dont know how work DJANGO, but my guess is `Entity.objects.all` represent a table in your DB.

So something like:

```
SELECT E.*, O.*
FROM `Entity.objects.all` E  -- 2000 records just make sure also have index on name
LEFT JOIN `organization` O   -- 600,000 records
  ON  E.name = O.company_name
WHERE O.company_name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was doing a "like" instead of an "equal" to search.

```
select * from organization 
where organization.name like '%my company%'
```

I changed it to:

```
select * from organization 
where organization.name = 'my company'
```

And the query finished within 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I tought about that `'contain'` was suspicious but not familiar with django. Still I think 5 seconds is a lot for that loop, instead you should try to execute the `LEFT JOIN` as I show in my answer. Doing 2000 querys isnt efficient and isnt scalable.